# Perform arbitrary code in grunt multitask

Tags: gruntjs

A grunt syntax question for someone - can't seem to find the answer in their docs. Say I have a grunt task set up like so:

```
grunt.registerTask('prod', [
    'clean',
    'md5:requireJS',
    'handlebars',
    'md5:cssFile',
]);
```

I need to perform some arbitrary code at the end of it, e.g.

```
grunt.registerTask('prod', [
    'clean',
    'md5:requireJS',
    'handlebars',
    'md5:cssFile',
    function() { ... }
]);
```

Syntactically, it doesn't seem like creating a new target would be of any use because it would just be an object, not a function. Any idea...? Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

(Thanks!) - Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a task to run at the end:

```
grunt.registerTask('end', function() {
  grunt.log.writeln('Im doing things at the end');
  /* ... */
});

grunt.registerTask('prod', [
    'clean',
    'md5:requireJS',
    'handlebars',
    'md5:cssFile',
    'end'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found a workaround. I found the grunt-exec task, which is really for running shell scripts. I bastardized it to simple run JS instead, e.g.

```
exec: {
    arbitraryJS: {
        cmd: function() {
            // do stuff

            // needed for the task
            return "";
        }
    }   
}
```

And then just added "exec:arbitraryJS" to the end of my task list.